# reason of slow share it app how to make it fast

Tags: file-transfer, 9.0-pie

I use share it app. The version on my Windows 10 desktop of Share it app is the latest and updated screenshot below
[image: app version]
[image: android app version]
Now when I try to transfer from my android phone anything to desktop using share it app there is speed variation I have captured screenshots these will make situation clear
[image: 0 kbps speed]
[image: 640 kbps speed]
[image: 745 kbps]
[image: 798 kbps]
[image: 2 Mbps speed]
You can see in the above screenshots speed for the same transfer is varying from 0 Kbps to 2 Mbps.
Occasionally large transfers broke also as in the screenshot above 9 Gb telegram files could not be transferred.

So I want to understand what is the problem. Which log file I can check to understand the problems and how can these be fixed? Is there a better solution for me?

Mobile phone is having android 9 OS.XiaoMi A3

Comment: I have the same problem